# creating an exe file from a .py file, python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've got a .py program written in python 3.7, that I need to convert to a .exe
My program imports different libaries such as pandas and numpy, everything must be convertet smoothly.
Is there a simple way to do sych a conversion?
Pyinstaller takes ages to convert and exe crashes after first input.

Comment: have you tried auto-py-to-exe? This tutorial and the comments are pretty useful: https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi

Comment: This is a pretty non-specific question, anything that is going to make a executable is going to take some time to make the executable. As for the crashing, it's impossible to guess why your specific program is crashing, it could be an import issue, or a typo, usually it's an issue with your handling of the current working directory. But I have used pyinstaller with pandas and numpy in the past.